# Why is Perforce adding a version of files with a percent symbol on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, perforce

When I sync my Perforce depot on Windows 10, it adds two versions of some files: one with a percent sign on front. This P4 depot works fine on OSX, and the P4 server is hosted on OSX.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ran into this issue myself today. Wish there was an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `<apple>` filetype.  Files of type `apple` have resource forks on Mac platforms, and since the concept of a resource fork doesn't exist on Windows (or at least didn't back in 1999 when this functionality was implemented in Perforce), the contents of the resource fork are synced (and submitted) as a `%` sidecar file.

Mac platform notes: https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2999#FILEMGMT-FORK

Note that "forked" files are considered "legacy" functionality at this point and are no longer standard for most Mac tools -- I'd recommend looking at the history of the file to see who/where they were added, and figure out how they were originally created in the workspace.  It could be that this is actually a normal file and the user was confused and manually forced the `apple` type on it when adding it (don't do this), or it could be that the user's image editor is misconfigured somehow.

If you change the filetype to `binary` that should cause the resource fork (and the weird `%` file) to go away.

Comment: Windows and NTFS does have "alternate data streams", which I believe were added specifically so that it could store resource forks when acting as AFP server...

Comment: If that's the case, I'm pretty sure Perforce never added support for them.  File a ticket with support@perforce.com...